# how to handle script time out for javascript executer for fetch call

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, fetch-api

I am executing the below javascript using selenium java script exceuter, I want to return the response fromt the fetch call and want to store it in java variable in code.
But below code is showing script time out, any suggestions how can I achive above requirements ???

```
 String location = "!async function(){\n" +
                "let data = await fetch(\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/LEXICON/master/lexiconLogo.png\")\n" +
                "    .then((response) => response.blob())\n" +
                "    .then(data => {\n" +
                "        return data;\n" +
                "    })\n" +
                "    .catch(error => {\n" +
                "        console.error(error);\n" +
                "    });\n" +
                "\n" +
                "console.log(data);\n" +
                "return data;\n" +
                "}();\n";


        Object str = js.executeAsyncScript(location);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not how to escape the quotes but the javascript should be:

```
let url = "https://..."
fetch(url).then(r => r.blob()).then(arguments[0])
```

arguments[0] is the callback, it needs to call that within 30 seconds or the timeout happens

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout()`

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: "resolved"
}
```

[async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

[How to useexecuteAsyncScriptmethodinorg.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor/executeAsyncScript)

Comment: But how do I execute that prmise with selenium executeAsyncScript() method, I mean how do I store the final result into java variable